# python 2.7 installing packages using pip on windows returns SSL error

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pip

The environment is python 2.7.15 on a Windows 7 PC (Win7 must be used due to user requirements). When attempting to install packages such as plotly and scipy, the below error is returned.

```
     Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certifica
    te: {'crlDistributionPoints': (u'http://cdp.rapidssl.com/RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crl'
    ,), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.logicnow.us'), ('DNS', 'logicnow.us')), 'notBe
    fore': u'Mar 14 00:00:00 2018 GMT', 'caIssuers': (u'http://cacerts.rapidssl.com/
    RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crt',), 'OCSP': (u'http://status.rapidssl.com',), 'serialNumb
    er': u'035BBD7099460760E357EF1F5E12C586', 'notAfter': 'May 12 12:00:00 2020 GMT'
    , 'version': 3L, 'subject': ((('commonName', u'*.logicnow.us'),),), 'issuer': ((
    ('countryName', u'US'),), (('organizationName', u'DigiCert Inc'),), (('organizat
    ionalUnitName', u'www.digicert.com'),), (('commonName', u'RapidSSL TLS RSA CA G1
    '),))}
      Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
     after connection broken by 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonho
    sted.org' doesn't match either of '*.logicnow.us', 'logicnow.us'",),)': /package
    s/c4/0c/1b8241395302fd66b34a0fe0774ed83632afd14aa5c995b262fb7b3ac540/plotly-2.7.
    0.tar.gz
      Certificate did not match expected hostname: files.pythonhosted.org. Certifica
    te: {'crlDistributionPoints': (u'http://cdp.rapidssl.com/RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crl'
    ,), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.logicnow.us'), ('DNS', 'logicnow.us')), 'notBe
    fore': u'Mar 14 00:00:00 2018 GMT', 'caIssuers': (u'http://cacerts.rapidssl.com/
    RapidSSLTLSRSACAG1.crt',), 'OCSP': (u'http://status.rapidssl.com',), 'serialNumb
    er': u'035BBD7099460760E357EF1F5E12C586', 'notAfter': 'May 12 12:00:00 2020 GMT'
    , 'version': 3L, 'subject': ((('commonName', u'*.logicnow.us'),),), 'issuer': ((
    ('countryName', u'US'),), (('organizationName', u'DigiCert Inc'),), (('organizat
    ionalUnitName', u'www.digicert.com'),), (('commonName', u'RapidSSL TLS RSA CA G1
    '),))}
    Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=
    'files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/c4
    /0c/1b8241395302fd66b34a0fe0774ed83632afd14aa5c995b262fb7b3ac540/plotly-2.7.0.ta
    r.gz (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'files.pythonhosted.org' doe
    sn't match either of '*.logicnow.us', 'logicnow.us'",),))
```

I have tried to use the below command which returns the following error.

```
pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org plotly
```

Error:

```
Collecting plotly
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/0c/1b8241395302fd66b34a
0fe0774ed83632afd14aa5c995b262fb7b3ac540/plotly-2.7.0.tar.gz
     - 10kB 1.5MB/s
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have u
pdated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the pa
ckage contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    plotly from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/0c/1b8241395302fd66b3
4a0fe0774ed83632afd14aa5c995b262fb7b3ac540/plotly-2.7.0.tar.gz#sha256=f7305816a4
23fd899da20919282445703118aeece19a54fb97be4cbf302341f8:
        Expected sha256 f7305816a423fd899da20919282445703118aeece19a54fb97be4cbf302341f8
             Got        5bc26e972b40ab4355857a8140d0ef730b267cfe26e8aff2a8dca148f227e5d7
```

Is there an alternative to installing packages?

Comment: You appear to be being served a **different** package, from a **different host**. Do not trust your network connection, something appears to be redirecting your traffic.

Comment: The serial number in the error message does *not* match that on the certificate I can see when accessing files.pythonhosted.org (which is 0C:3B:77:0C:98:2F:CB:FC:7B:00:B7:4A, for `r.ssl.fastly.net`, one of a series of CDN hosts).

Comment: Looks like you are behind a [LogicNow network security device](https://www.solarwindsmsp.com/), redirecting your traffic. Perhaps `files.pythonhosted.org` is *blocked* at your office? You need to go talk to your IT department.